# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/cloudsql/my_project:us-central1:my_instance\'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

This is the first time I'm deploying on Google cloud, and I'm cloning my repository from GitHub.

Everything seemed ok from creating a directory, cloning the GitHub repo, creating an instances and a MySQL database. Installing requirements also was successful. I created an cloud SQL second generation database and set a user as well as a password for it. I even enabled cloud SQL API.

When I run server with "`sudo python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`", I get this error message:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, 'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/cloudsql/my_project:us-central1:my_instance\' (2 "No such file or directory")')
```

I tried running the server with: `sudo python3 manage.py runserver` and still get the same error.

I have given myself several hours to try solving this error, all to no avail.

It's a Django app, and the setings.py DATABASES looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/my_instance:us-central1:my_project_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '**password**',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
                     }
             }
```

I tried the settings without a password, and got the same error.

I have tried all I can think of without any success. 
Please, I need help. I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: How do you create your cloud SQL proxy? In socket mode?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test

Comment: Hello, have you tried the Django example from App Engine? It uses PyMySQL and is designed for App Engine deploy and running the app locally. https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to run the application? The `/cloudsql` socket is only provided automatically to [App Engine runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) - if you want to run locally you need to use the [Cloud SQL Proxy to create a socket locally](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I use Cloud SQL Proxy and 'HOST':'127.0.0.1' and it works:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '**password**',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
               }
             }
```

Here're the manuals:

https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#mysql-client
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test